# How to add VS2017 extensions to Host Agent

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm currently setting continuous integration server in VSTS. I have a VS2017 app with some references to an SDK I had to install in visual studio in order to make it work. When I set up a build in VSTS it fails because it doesn't find the extensions I have installed in the SDKs section.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2195,5): Error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "PDFTron.PDFNetUWPApps, Version=6.5.4.47152".
```

How can I include them in the Host Agent of the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to add a folder library with the SDKs from:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UAP
```

that I needed and added this to the csproj file of the app.

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot>..\SDKs;</SDKReferenceDirectoryRoot>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Even though the VSTS agent doesn't complain when finding and enumerating the SDKs, It is yielding an error while compilating the Solution.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can’t add/change any software for hosted agent, you can just use the software it has.

For your situation, you can use **Hosted VS2017** agent instead, it has [VS2017 installed](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#hosted-vs2017).